# filter google sheets in app script with html

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help with this code I found online. The google sheets filter function is working but it displays the results in a table. I am looking to see if any body know how to display the result on the sheet itself.

```
    function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('FilterHeaders');
  htmlOutput.miles = '';
  htmlOutput.color = '';
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}


function doPost(e) {
  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));

  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('FilterHeaders');
  htmlOutput.miles =  e.parameter.miles;
  htmlOutput.color =  e.parameter.color;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();     

}

function getSheetData()  { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data'); 
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();  
  return dataValues;
}

function getUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}
```

Here is the HTML. I have the sheet imported in a webpage. I need the filter to update the sheet itself when you apply the filter and not a table.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Web App Filter Headers</h1>
    <?var tableData = getSheetData();?>
    <?var url = getUrl();?>
    <form method="post" action="<?= url ?>" >
    <label>Color</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="color" value="<?= color ?>" /><br>
    <label>Miles</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="miles" value="<?= miles ?>" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="searchButton" value="Search" /><br>
    </form><br>
    
   <? if(color != '' || miles != '')
    {
        var output_array = [];
        tableData.forEach(function(value, index) {
        
          if(index == 0)
          {
            output_array.push(value);
          }
          else if(index > 0 && color != '' && miles != '')
          {
            if(value[0].toLowerCase() == color.toLowerCase() && value[2] == miles)
            {
              output_array.push(value);
             }
            }
            else if(index > 0 && color != '')
            {
              if(value[0].toLowerCase() == color.toLowerCase())
              {                       
                output_array.push(value);
              }            
            }
            else if(index > 0 && miles != '')
            {
              if(value[2] == miles)
              {                       
                output_array.push(value);
              }           
            }                           
        });
    }
    else
    {
      var output_array = tableData;    
    }  ?>
    
    
    
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5px" >
    <?for(var i = 0; i < output_array.length; i++) { ?>
      <?if(i == 0) { ?>
        <tr>
        <?for(var j = 0; j < output_array[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <th><?= output_array[i][j] ?></th>
        <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } else { ?>
        <tr>
        <? for(var j = 0; j < output_array[i].length; j++) { ?>
          <td><?= output_array[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    <? } ?>
    </table>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

The image below is what I am looking for. You see how the display is on the Google Sheets itself.
[image: This is what I am looking for]

After applying the filter, Google sheets only show your filtered option

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `display the result on the sheet itself.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I understand. If you look at this code, the filtered records are displayed on a table in the web app. What i want is, once you put in the color and miles you want to filter, it should show the results on the google sheet, not the table in the web app. So it will hide everything except the filtered records.

Comment: @Tanaike, I added images of what I am looking for. Can you look to see if you can help?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. Can I ask you about the relationship between your added images and the HTML in your question? And, in your expected result, for example, when the spreadsheet is filtered, do you want to irreversibly reflect the filter? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: The added images show the HTML section, which is the dropdown. Once the spreadsheet is filtered, I need it to reverse back to the complete list once they are done. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're approaching this the wrong way. Apps Script [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) are meant to display data separate from the Sheet. You cannot inject the HTML into a Sheet like in your screenshot. If you want this search function within the Sheet itself you can just use queries and data validation. For example:

- Have a "Data" sheet with all your values:

[image]

- Create a "Search" sheet where you can choose your parameters:

[image]

- Create the dropdowns with [Data Validation](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10107325) rules. In my example I just pulled the dropdown values from the existing "Data" sheet but you can set them manually too:

[image]

[image]

- Finally just use a query in the cell where you want to display your results:

[image]

The [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) I used is this: `=IFERROR(QUERY(Data!A3:B, "select * where A matches '"&IF(B2="Any", ".*", B2)&"' and B matches '"&IF(D2="Any", ".*", D2)&"'"), "No results")`. Add parameters or columns as needed.

So pretty much if you want some sort of search *within a Sheet*, you'll have to work with formulas. Your HTML code is for displaying on a separate page, or you could also display it in a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs), though this doesn't quite look like what you're looking for in your screenshot.

Comment: I decided to display it on a web app now. This is the code.